# import Visio diagram into draw.io automatically (with api, with script..)

Tags: import, draw.io

I am using mxgraph since a lot of time for creating diagrams and saving into database.
I saw that with drawio i can import Visio files. question is how to do it more automatically.. i want to save it in database so i can easily search.

in mxgraph this happened with

```
window.OPEN_URL
window.SAVE_URL
```

Here, i don't see this functionality. My question is - is there an automated way to import visio diagrams by api for example.

thank you !
*emphasized text*